# Jquery mobile: Header is visible and then immediately disappears when page is fully rendered

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

... in fact all markup that i put before the

```
<div data-role="page">...</div>
```

is visible a very little time and when page is fully rendered, all these content disappears. Its still visible in Source / Firebug although.

i'm using HTML5Boilerplate for this project. Here's some code - maybe there are some collisions that i didn't find?!

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- header disappears after page is rendered :( //-->
<div data-role="header">
 Here goes the Head-Content
</div>

<h3>This content disappears also :( ... </h3>

<!-- everything below this point stays visible! //-->
<div data-role="page">...</div>    
</body>

...

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Have tried to comment or move this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js">
</script>` after `jquery.mobile` include?

Comment: a jquery mobile `data-role=header` goes inside `data-role=page`, `page` isn't a container for your content, it is the entire page you want to serve.

Comment: Andy has the correct solution. I would write it up but he should.

Comment: i bow my head in shame :) Thank's to Andy for pointing out my error in designing the page. Problem solved!

Comment: @andleer haha there you go :)

Comment: @andy, where do you live? Funny stuff. I wish there was a way to contact other users here on SO. Me: Bellingham WA.

Comment: @andleer Uhm, England lol, why?

Comment: No particular reason. Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As asked :)

In jQuery mobile, `data-role="page"` isn't a container for your content, it is literally the page that you want to serve, anything else won't be shown. You need to put your `data-role="header"` inside `data-role="page"`, and it will work

Basic jQuery mobile page from [jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Page Title</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

  // Anything here will not be on the page   

  <div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header">...</div> 
    <div data-role="content">...</div> 
    <div data-role="footer">...</div> 
  </div> 

  // Anything here will not be on the page

</body>
</html>
```

[Proof here](http://jsfiddle.net/BZunS/1/)